# Error while selecting a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel, range

I want to select the range described below to format it. However, it says that there is an Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.

```
With ws3.Range("C8", "C12", "L14:P16", "L20:P20", "L22:Q23", "L" & lastrow5 & ":" & "Q" & lastrow5)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it like this...

```
With ws3.Range("C8, C12, L14:P16, L20:P20, L22:Q23, L" & lastrow5 & ":Q" & lastrow5)
```

Comment: thank you very much.. If you can help I have one more question. I wanted to format a this new range                                                            
With ws3.Range("C8:C12,C9:C11,L16:P20,L17:P19,L23:Q" & lastrow5 & ", L24:Q" & lastrow5 -1 & ") ..... It gives a syntax error. (also, if you see, I say lastrow5 -1 because I want the row before the last row)

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas You're welcome! You may try it like ws3.Range("C8:C12,C9:C11,L16:P20,L17:P19,L23:Q" & lastrow5 & ", L24:Q" & lastrow5 - 1)

Answer (score 1):

As *IntelliSense* is telling you (assuming `ws3` is declared `As Worksheet`), `Worksheet.Range` takes up to 2 arguments: `[Cell1]` and `[Cell2]`.

In VBA you separate arguments using a comma. So this:

```
ws3.Range("C8", "C12", "L14:P16", "L20:P20", "L22:Q23", "L" & lastrow5 & ":" & "Q" & lastrow5)
```

Is attempting to invoke `Worksheet.Range` with 6 arguments, and VBA doesn't know what to do with it, hence "wrong number of arguments".

If you mean to give it a union'd range string, then [give it a single string argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46834074/1188513).